# Anaconda 1.10 installation how to create new environments with Python 3.7 rather than 3.8?

Tags: python3, anaconda

I installed Anaconda 1.10 (Win 10 Home, 64-bit, 20H2; with installer Anaconda3-2020.11-Windows-x86_64)

When I tried to create a new environment, only Python 3.8 was offered. How do I create a new environment with 3.7?

Thanks

Comment: *"When I tried to create a new environment, only Python 3.8 was offered."* - Have you tried something like `conda create --name YourEnvName python=3.7 anaconda`?

Comment: @Anaksunaman Yes, just did that in fact, but it's a plain environment and - IIRC - previously I could create with py (3.6), 3.7, 3.8 and get a copy of the base with the right python version - or am I misremembering?